# tcl and gnuplot interaction

Tags: tcl, gnuplot

Currently, I will tcl handle the data processing part. Let's say the data is stored in a tcl list variable.
If I want to use gnuplot to show the data. what is the best way to do this.
Based on my study, gnuplot needs data file provided. so I can not directly pass the list variable to gnuplot command. 
I guess that creating the gnu command inside tcl with string operation. and then print all the command into a file,for example name it "command.dat". 
And call the gnuplot this way in tcl: 
exec gnuplot "command.dat"

any other method? or good reference.

Comment: Putting the data into a file (tab-separated values?) and the commands into another always worked for me. If you're doing that, you might find it easiest to write a procedure that takes the string to write and returns the name of a temporary file that it wrote it to…

Comment: gnuplot is written in tcl .. you can write your own small gnuplot using Tk.. It will be lot easier for you then i guess..